# Serialization - WebApi para WCF com propriedade tipo base (abstract)

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf, asp.net-web-api, serialização

estou com um problema aqui onde tenho uma WebApi consumindo um WCF. Basicamente estou tendo problema ao receber no WCF uma propriedade que é o tipo base da classe que realmente estou enviando. Vou colocar um exemplo pra ficar mais fácil explicar:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(EnderNacional))]
[KnownType(typeof(EnderInternacional))]
public abstract class EnderBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Logradouro { get; set; }
    ///...
}

[DataContract]
public class EnderNacional : EnderBase
{
    public String Cep { get; set; }
    ///...
}

[DataContract]
public class EnderInternacional : EnderBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public String CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    ///...

}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CliNacional))]
[KnownType(typeof(CliInternacional))]
public abstract class CliBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<EnderBase> Enderecos { get; set; }
    ///...
}

[DataContract]
public class CliNacional : CliBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Cnpj { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CliInternacional : CliBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Identificacao { get; set; }
}
```

Aqui coloquei um exemplo de uma classe cliente nacional e internacional, que herdam de uma classe base. O mesmo acontece com endereços onde existe o nacional e o internacional herdando de classe base para endereço. Para quem já trabalhou com WCF certamente já teve o problema com classes abstratas e por isso o uso de "**KnownType**" para que o WCF possa serializar o objeto passado.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceClientes
{
    [OperationContract]
    int SalvarNacional(ServiceClientes.CliNacional cliente);
}

public class ServiceClientes : IServiceClientes
{
    public int SalvarNacional(Clientes.CliNacional cliente)
    {
        //...código
        return int.MinValue;
    }
}
```

O código acima é uma representação da implementação de **IServiceClientes**.

Isso funciona bem quando eu testo diretamente pelo *WCFTestClient.exe*, quando vou informar o endereço, aparece também o **EnderNacional** e **EnderInternacional** para escolha. Assim, basta optar por um dos dois, preencher as informações e pronto, o C# consegue serializar o objeto pois conhece aquele tipo, graças ao **KnownType**. Sei que existem outras formas e até dinâmicas de fazer isso mas isso não vem ao caso.

Meu problema começa quando eu uso um WebApi para consumir este método e disponibilizar para os **Clients**. Exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SalvarClienteNacional(Api.CliNacional clienteNacional)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new MyService.ServiceClientesClient().SalvarNacional(clienteNacional));
    }
```

Aqui é um simples exemplo de uma chamada ao meu WCF através do WebApi, supondo que MyService é o meu serviço WCF devidamente mapeado.

Quando vou testar o WebApi, enviado corretamente o objeto JSON eu recebo ele corretamente no meu parametro "**clienteNacional**", porém o mesmo vem com a propriedade "**Enderecos**" mapeado como "**EnderBase**" e quando isso é enviado para o WCF recebo um exception de que não é possível instanciar uma classe abstrata.

Provavelmente o WCF não consegue entender que meu JSON representa um endereço nacional ou internacional ou porque a propriedade "Enderecos" está mapeada como sendo a classe base, que realmente é abstrata! No momento do cast parece que ele tenta instanciar o próprio tipo da collection, gerando o exception.

Googlei bastante e só encontro a mesma solução que já estou usando, que é o uso de KnownType mas parece que isso funcionou somente quando eu uso diretamente as classe do WCF, não quando é feito o cast através de um JSON.

O que eu poderia fazer para resolver este problema? Alguém já teve problema semelhante?

Toda e qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Agraço a todos antecipadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você seguiu os passos certos, provavelmente se esqueceu das outras partes.

1) Você analisou um pouco, o WCF isoladamente. Não há diferença de comportamentos, o que funciona com o WCFTestClient, funciona em qualquer lugar. Mas fique atento, há chances de você ter alterado seu WCF e não ter regerado seu Service Reference.

2) Você disse que analisou o Json, Ok, mas analisou o que o Model Binder efetivamente entregou para seu controller? Use brakepoints para validar se seu objeto está chegando à sua Action corretamente, é bem provável que seja na deserialização do WebApi seu problema, é possível que seja ausência de attributos específicos para o Model Binder do WebApi.

3) Dá para ver que você está usando a mesma classe que seu serviço usa, no seu WebApi. Bom, para servir de mero Proxy, sem inteligência alguma, não há necessidade do WebApi. Utilizando um binding correto para WCF você hospedaria com segurança o que você precisa.

[ ]'s

Comment: Com relação aos 3 itens: 1) eu regerei sim meu service reference; 2) no WebApi eu verifiquei sim a estrutura do objeto e estava ok, ou seja, do json para a api não estava com problemas. Porém não sei quais são esses atributos específicos para o Model Binder, poderia me ajudar? 3) Essa estrutura de ter um WebApi foi exigência do cliente, onde o WCF ficaria somente local e só o api visível na Web.